# Sharing a Hard drive on Centos and using samba

Tags: linux, hard-drive, permissions, centos, samba

I am having issues sharing a external hard drive using samba on centos. I am able to view the share group from my windows machine but when I attempt to accsess it, it says "you do not have permission to access"

I have tried the "force user = account" solution as well as the setting the group 777

I have included my configuration below

```
[global]

    security = user
    idmap config * :backend = tbd
    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw
    netbios name= Centos
    force user = Home
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S, Home
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes
    create mask = 0600
    browseable = No

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
    write list = @printadmin root
    force group = @printadmin
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
[homefiles]
#sharegroup for desktop

path =  /srv/samba/homefiles
guest ok = Yes
browsable = Yes
writable = Yes
read only = no
force user = Home

[ExternalDrive]
#external drive 2tb

path = /run/media/Home/MYDRIVE
guest ok = yes
read only = no
force user = Home
browsable = yes
```

Comment: Also I am unable to see the force user or browsable commands under testparm which may be where my problem is coming from

Comment: Once disable SElinux and check. Command to disable SElinux is  'setenforce 0'

Comment: That did the trick! I am still not able to see the force user under testparm but I am not able to reach the drive from windows

Comment: I think it's because of in [global] section you already mentioned force user to Home. If you give some other name it will show in testparm.

Comment: No dice on the removing force user under global to allow for the force user and browsable to show up under the external hard drive using testparm

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to mount hard driver in other folder.
Example: `/cdrom`.

Comment: How would OP do that? How would that help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and welcome to Superuser. Although readers familiar with the subject might now what you mean, it would be helpful for everyone else to elaborate on your answer a little further. For example explain how to do this in a step by step manner and, if possible, add screen shots.